# Engine temperature gauge stays on cold

Tags: engine, hyundai, temperature

I have a 2011 Hyundai equus and all of a sudden my temperature gauge stays on cold I checked my coolant level and it was low in which I added the correct amount and drove for awhile but temp gauge is still on cold any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Does the car's motor reach operating temperature? If it does, there's something wrong with the gauge or its wiring. If it does not, I'd suspect the thermostat has failed open.

Comment: @David why put this in a comment and not in an answer?

Comment: @Mad marky, It's a guess there's not enough detail in the for a definate answer.

Comment: @MadMarky The site seems to disallow having to ask questions in the answer... Which really doesn't make sense to me either.

Comment: @MadMarky, when I commented I thought the question lacked enough info to be sure. This morning...I can easily second-guess myself and think there *is* enough info. If the OP lets us know in the comments that it was indeed one of my alternatives, I can offer the same dx as an answer.

Comment: it sounds like  the temperature sending unit...try grounding the unit wire if it moves the gauge then it is the unit

Comment: Check your engine temp sensor, brass piece sticking out of the engine with a wire going to it, ohms should drop when heat is applied

Answer (score 0):

Does the engine come up to operating temperature after driving it a few miles?

You can check this by feeling the upper radiator hose to see if it hot, careful not to grab it as it could burn your hand, just touch it slightly with a finger, it should be very hot.

Another way is to connect an OBD scanner to the OBD port on the car after it has run a few miles and see what the engine temp is, the ecu uses a separate engine temp sensor, if it reads 180 degrees Fahrenheit or above the engine temp gauge for the instrument cluster is bad or you may have an engine thermostat that needs replaced.

Comment: Thanks for the info, it was the engine temperature sensor